# How should I reattach my patio door weather strip?

Tags: doors, windows

[image]

I have a patio door and the weather strip appears to have come off. It's looks like it's designed to snap into place, but I can't figure out how to do it. Any ideas?!

Here's the door with the groove the piece fits into. The groove has some form of gray felt liner.

I can't find information on the manufacturer.

[image: groove on door for weather strip]

[image]

Comment: Additional photo added. Can't find window manufactuer info.

Comment: Please try again with focus as a priority. I can't tell what I'm looking at.  :) Maybe leave the door open a bit so it's more apparent what's door and what's frame.

Comment: I'll do that when I get home. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that the door was installed improperly. This was the non sliding door, so the felt should have been in groove sealed against the wall, not in the groove which the weather strip attaches to.

The felt was stopping the weather strip from going in properly. Flipped the door and presto, the weather strip hammers in  perfectly on the unfelted groove.